# Deleted instance passed to merge Error - Understanding why this happens in certain cases

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a One to Many relationship between a School and Student entities (using Spring Data JPA)

While trying to retrieving current list of students and delete them using the piece of code below, i get the following error

```
School school = schoolRepo.findOne(schoolId);
Set<Student> students = school.getStudents();
studentRepo.delete(students);
schoolRepo.saveAndFlush(school);
```

> deleted instance passed to merge: [com.api.beans.Student#]

However, when i modify the getStudents part of code with custom query as follows, it **works perfectly fine**

```
School school = schoolRepo.findOne(schoolId);
Set<Student> students = studentRepo.findBySchool(schoolId);
studentRepo.delete(students);
schoolRepo.saveAndFlush(school);
```

where the findBySchool custom query is defined in studentRepo as below

```
 @Query("SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE  s.school.schoolId =:schoolId")
 Set<Student> findBySchool(@Param("schoolId") Long schoolId);
```

Why is this so ? I feel there is some conceptual clarity I am missing and would like to understand so.

Basically, what is the difference between these two lines ?

```
Set<Student> students = school.getStudents();
Set<Student> students = studentRepo.findBySchool(schoolId);
```

Why does the first line give an error while the second method work fine ?

Comment: JPA does not clean up your object model for you - it is up to you to keep it in synch with what you are doing in the database. If you want to delete students, you should first remove (clear or null) any references to them from other entities.  In this case, call school.getStudents().clear() or the like beforehand.  Your code works in the opposite case likely because the school.getStudents() reference hasn't been fetched from the database yet before the students are removed.

Comment: Also, if the business rules of your app forbid school-less students to exist and `School` is the owning side, consider using `orphanRemoval=true`. Clearing `school.students` will then suffice